# Toral rank conjecture

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

In 1985,  S.~Halperin conjectured in the topological context of maximal free torus actions on topological manifolds, that:

If $X$ is a topological space, then $$\dim H^*(X;\mathbb Q)\geq 2^{rk(X)}.$$

Where $rk(X):=\max\{n\in\mathbb{N};\text{ such that }\mathbb{T}^n\text{ acts almost freely on } X\}$ is the toral rank of $X$.

My first question: TRC is obvious for $rk(X)=0$ or 1. Do we know for which values of $rk(X)\geq 2$ the conjecture holds?.

Any comments and references are welcome

Answer (score 4):

Volker Puppe has proved the conjecture for $rk_0(X)\le 3$, see the introduction [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.3685.pdf) with a reference to the article of [Puppe](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.3517.pdf). There seems to be no general result for $rk(X)\ge 2$.
The Lie algebra version, for nilpotent Lie algebras, has been proved for many classes of nilpotent Lie algebras (e.g., $2$-step nilpotent, or low dimension, see Proposition $2.2.7$ [here](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_11_habil.pdf)).

Comment: Thanks Dietrich. Just note that following both USTIONOVSKY introduction and Puppe Theorem 1.1, the rational TRC is resolved for $rk_0(X)\geq 3$.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Ustionovsky says $m\le 3$, right ?

Comment: Yes, TRC is ok for $rk_0(X)\leq 3$. For $rk_0(X)\geq 3$, Puppe bounded the rational cohomological dimension by 2(r+1). Is there any other best approximation?

Comment: I'v found the following: Aman showed in 2012 see  [arXiv:1204.6276](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.6276) that $$\dim H^*(X;\mathbb Q)\geq 2(r+[r/3]).$$ 20 years before, Hilali proved in 1990 (see [Theorem D](http://algtop.net/docs/divers/Theses/TheseHilali.djvu)) that $$\dim H^*(X;\mathbb Q)\geq 2(r^2+r).$$

Comment: @MyIsmail: I think the $2$ in the second bound should be $1/2$.

Comment: @MarkGrant : Yes ideed the inequality is: $\dim H^∗(X;\mathbb Q)\geq \frac 12(r^2+r)$.